# Vue 3 / Vite Okta GetAccessToken() - how do I call it?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, access-token, okta

Converting a Vue 2 to a Vue 3 using Vite for a client/server REST API.

In Vue 2, after a successful login to the Okta Widget, I could get the okta accessToken like this:

authUtils.js

```
import Vue from "vue";

//Get the auth token and set the header for Axios calls
export default async function getAuthHeader () {
    return {'headers': {'Authorization': `Bearer ${await Vue.prototype.$auth.getAccessToken()}`}}
}
```

old Tips.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="store-tips">
        <div class="container"  id="ph-nav">

            <!-- LOAD STORE TIPS BUTTON-->
            <button id="get-tips"
                    v-on:click="getTipsData()"
                    v-bind:disabled="storesLoading"
                    class="btn-sm btn-outline-primary">
                <i class="fas fa-spin fa-atom" v-if="storesLoading"></i>
                {{ storesLoading ? '' : 'Load Store Tips - Text'}}
            </button>

        </div>
        <hr>
        <ul>
            <h5>Adjust Store Tips</h5>
            <h6> {{ message }} </h6>
            <p></p>
            <li>
                <Tabulate v-bind:tableData="tableData" @post-tips-event="postTipsData()" ref="tableRef"></Tabulate>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    let axios = require ('axios').default;
    let config = require ('../../config');
    import Tabulate from '../components/StoreTipsTabulate'
    import getAuthHeader from '../authUtils';

    export default {
        name: "StoreTips",
        components: {
            Tabulate
        },

        data() {
            return {
                storesLoading: false,
                tipsSaveDisabled: true,
                message: "Instructions: Load Store Tips with the button above. ",
                baseMessage: "Instructions: Edit store tips as needed.",
                //data for table to display
                tableData: [],
                //response object from Okta
                authResponse: {}
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            //Set the url for the axios calls when the component is mounted
            axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_SERVER_BASE_URL
        },
        methods: {
            flashMessage: function (message) {
                this.message = message;
                let self = this;
                setTimeout(function () {self.message = self.baseMessage;}, 10000);
            },
            getTipsData: async function () {
                // Routes over to the express server router, not Vue router
                this.storesLoading = true; //turn on the button spinner when starting
                axios.get('/getTipsData', await getAuthHeader())
                    .then( (response) => {
                    this.tableData = response.data;
                    this.tipsSaveDisabled = false; //turn on the save tips button once data is loaded
                    this.flashMessage("Data Loaded Successfully!!");
                    this.$refs.tableRef.displayTable(this.tableData);
                    })
                    .catch( (e) => {
                        this.message = "Error in GetTipsData: " + e;
                    })
                    .finally(() => {
                        this.storesLoading = false; //turn off the button spinner when complete
                    })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it in Vue 3, as the Vue.prototype does not exist.

I found that the authState is now on "this". So I tried:

new Tips.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="store-tips">
        <div class="container" id="ph-nav">

            <!-- LOAD STORE TIPS BUTTON-->
            <button id="get-tips"
                    v-on:click="getTipsData()"
                    v-bind:disabled="storesLoading"
                    class="btn-sm btn-outline-primary">
                <i class="fas fa-spin fa-atom" v-if="storesLoading"></i>
                {{ storesLoading ? '' : 'Load Store Tips - Text'}}
            </button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <ul>
            <h5>Adjust Store Tips</h5>
            <h6> {{ message }} </h6>
            <p></p>
            <li>
                <Tabulate v-bind:tableData="tableData" v-on:post-tips-event="postTipsData()" ref="tableRef"></Tabulate>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    //let axios = require ('axios').default;
    import axios from 'axios';
    import config from '../../config';
    // 2023.07.24 Added for Vue 3 to get accessToken
    import OktaVue from '@okta/okta-vue';
    // 2023.03.07 changed import to require 
    import Tabulate from '../components/StoreTipsTabulate.vue';
    
    // 2023.03.07 changed import to require 
    //import getAuthHeader from '../authUtils';
    //const getAuthHeader = require ('../authUtils');

    export default {
        name: "StoreTips",
        components: {
            Tabulate
        },
        data() {
            return {
                storesLoading: false,
                tipsSaveDisabled: true,
                message: "Instructions: Load Store Tips with the button above. ",
                baseMessage: "Instructions: Edit store tips as needed.",
                //data for table to display
                tableData: [],
                //response object from Okta
                authResponse: {}
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.defaults.baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SERVER_BASE_URL;
        },
        methods: {
            flashMessage: function (message) {
                this.message = message;
                let self = this;
                setTimeout(function () {self.message = self.baseMessage;}, 10000);
            },
            getTipsData: async function () {
                // Routes over to the express server router, not Vue router
                this.storesLoading = true; //turn on the button spinner when starting
                //axios.get('/getTipsData', await getAuthHeader())
                // construct the auth header from the authState object and store it in a variable
                const xxx = { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${ this.authState.accessToken }` }};
                axios.get('/getTipsData', { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${ this.authState.accessToken }` }})
                    .then( (response) => {
                    this.tableData = response.data;
                    this.tipsSaveDisabled = false; //turn on the save tips button once data is loaded
                    this.flashMessage("Data Loaded Successfully!!");
                    this.$refs.tableRef.displayTable(this.tableData);
                    })
                    .catch( (e) => {
                        this.message = "Error in GetTipsData: " + e;
                    })
                    .finally(() => {
                        this.storesLoading = false; //turn off the button spinner when complete
                    })
            },
         }
    }
</script>
```

But, this.authstate.accessToken is an object, not a string. Not sure what it is supposed to be (looks like it needs to be a Promise). Okta doco says getAccessToken() is a getter, but I'm getting an error saying it is not a function ("this.authState.getAccessToken is not a function").

If I use "this.authState.accessToken" directly, the header statement looks like this

> {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer [object Object]'}}

and the authAPI.js OktaJwtVerifier function on the server fails the authorization with a 401 error.

authAPI.js

```
//Authorization Code
const OktaJwtVerifier = require('@okta/jwt-verifier');

const oktaJwtVerifier = new OktaJwtVerifier({
    issuer: process.env.ISSUER // required
});
//Authorization Code
module.exports.authenticationRequired = function(req, res, next) {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization || '';
    const match = authHeader.match(/Bearer (.+)/);

    if (!match) {
        res.status(401);
        return next('Unauthorized');
    }
    const accessToken = match[1];
    return oktaJwtVerifier.verifyAccessToken(accessToken, 'api://default')
        .then((jwt) => {
            req.jwt = jwt;
            next();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(401).send(err.message);
        });
}
```

Comment: Vue.prototype.$auth is a quick and dirty workaround that shouldn't have been used under normal circumstances. It's unknown what's this.authState in your case. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask. Yes, I can expand my explanation. Okta uses the Vue.prototype for their recommended sample code for vue 2.

Comment: I may have overstated that "Okta" uses Vue.prototype.... Others do, but I haven't found one where okta did so.  (e.g. https://www.sitepoint.com/add-authentication-vue-okta/). Prob should be using `this.prototype.$auth` on the Vue 2 code.

Answer (score 0):

So, as it normally happens, when you explain the problem to someone, and get a little hint, you find the answer.

Finally found in the Okta docs that i should have and should still be using
`this.$auth.getAccessToken()`, especially in Vue 3.

Source: https://github.com/okta/okta-vue